# crystal-report problem + Oracle

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, oracle11g

i have build C# program that connect to Oracle and make some report's using crystal-report.
in my computer it work's excelent (when i bind to my Oracle)
but when i run my program on other computer - the program work and i see the data on the screen, but
when i try to see report with crystal report i get error (problem with connection to Oracle)
why i get this error ?  the connection is good , i see the data from the Oracle on the screen (in my program)

(my program in C# VS2008, Oracle 11g)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer. But this might help someone else.
I was initially working with MS SQL and Crystal report in my .NET MVC application. But the client was using Oracle and my application needed to contact a remote oracle DB. The connection was working fine but the connection of crystal report and oracle was giving intermittent issues.

So the final fix was to create DataSets. In my application before generating the report, I populated the DataSet with  data from Oracle. And used the DataSet as the Data Source for my report. It works great now.